# Php curl installed yet composer says its not

Tags: php, curl, composer-php

I am trying to get composer running solely for the purpose of updating my cc merchants files (since they are incompetent enough to make this the only way for downloading the api source)

I have an error from composer saying

```
Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-curl * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's curl extension.
```

I have curl installed (responds in cmd) and and enabled the extension in the php.ini files i have found. What am I missing?

Comment: Run `phpinfo();` and see if the extension is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to figure out how to get that to work with localhost, its easy on my server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have curl installed (responds in cmd) and and enabled the extension in the php.ini files i have found. What am I missing?

Hmm, it seems your are guessing around where the correct `php.ini` is in order to enable the PHP extension `curl`, right?

These steps might help you:

- Please run `php --ini` on the CLI to find the `php.ini` to edit (`Loaded Configuration File`).
- Then edit that `php.ini` and enable the PHP Extension `curl`.
- Test, that `curl` is available: `php --ri curl` (the command prints the extension configuration).
- Then run `composer` on the CLI again.

Comment: Correct about guessing lol. Turns out with your provided steps....I have no loaded php.ini file at all. Thanks, now I know what is going on and how to progress

Comment: :) Glad i could help.

Comment: Didn't work for me  `OSX w/homebrew, php 7.1, curl 7.53.1`

Comment: Hey this helped :kudos:

Answer (score 1):

Curl and php5 curl extension is a different application.

If you are using ubuntu / debian based unix, you can install it with `apt-get install php5-curl`.

If after installing php5-curl it still doesn't works, it's possible the extension still not enabled. You can enabled it by using command `php5enmod curl`.